# Get load time of javascript and css files for a website in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am a beginner with chrome extension development. I am trying to create and extension which will fetch the javascript and CSS file load time  for a particular website and display in the chrome extension popup.

However, I am unsure about the CHROME.API to achieve it

Please kindly suggest

Comment: There may be a better way to do it within an extension but on page you can use window.performance.getEntries() to get timings of all resources on a page

Comment: A [question very similar to yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503445/how-to-show-specific-js-load-time) was posted about 2 hours prior to yours. Is this a group project? Homework? A programming challenge?

Comment: Yea its a sort of group project :)

Comment: @Brian window.performance.getEntries()  function well great !!! hopefully i can use it in content script and render the data in the popup script of my extension !!! Hopefully it will yield solution !!! Many Thanks !!! Appreciated :)

Comment: You're very welcome - one thing to be aware of is that it'll update as resources so you either need to call it multiple times or be selective about when you call it. Things like AJAX requests or images will be listed here too. Also Firefox from memory has one slightly different behavior in that it includes 404'd requests whereas other browsers don't iirc. `performance.timing` (current request ie HTML page) might also be of interest to you and `performance.navigation` "request type" ie refresh as a history navigation will be heavilly cached resulting in many 0's in performance data :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the HAR log using this

```
chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(function callback)
```

**What are HAR logs?**

A HAR file contains a JSON data structure that describes the network "waterfall", which also contains the loading time of every resource of that page.

So you will need to parse the HAR JSON, extract time for the js and css files.

More on HAR structure : http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/